# how can i change the html code in crm form?

Tags: html, dynamics-crm

I used dynamics **CRM 2015** and i want to change the **OptionSet** type to **checkboxs**.
Just like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEVb9.png)

My solution is use **JQuery** get the **td** tag in crm form,and use **html()** change the **td** html code.
Like this *$("#ubg_note_d").html()*.But question comes that i can't get the  **td** tag which i want to display the checkbox.Only after i used the browser DEVELOPER TOOLS and select the element,then i can get the tag......i have blocked by this for 1 day,any helps?;)

note:i tried the js and jquery,both can't get the **td** tag.My code is run in the form **Onload** event,and i tried the filed **Onchange** event,trouble still there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing you are trying to achieve is unsupported. Instead you can achieve the same using supported way by creating html web resource, which can be added on form on later.

Code for web resource is as below.

```html
<html><head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="new_jquery_1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // function will be called when web resource is loaded on Form.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ConvertDropDownToCheckBoxList();
        });

        //Coverts option list to checkbox list.
        function ConvertDropDownToCheckBoxList() {
            var dropdownOptions = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_makeyear").getOptions();
            var selectedValue = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_selectedyears").getValue();

            $(dropdownOptions).each(function (i, e) {
                var rText = $(this)[0].text;
                var rvalue = $(this)[0].value;
                var isChecked = false;
                if (rText != '') {
                    if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue.indexOf(rvalue) != -1)
                        isChecked = true;

                    var checkbox = "< input type='checkbox' name='r' / >" + rText + ""
                    $(checkbox)
                        .attr("value", rvalue)
                        .attr("checked", isChecked)
                          .attr("id", "id" + rvalue)
                        .click(function () {
                            //To Set Picklist Select Values
                            var selectedOption = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_selectedyears").getValue();
                            if (this.checked) {
                                if (selectedOption == null)
                                    selectedOption = rvalue;
                                else
                                    selectedOption = selectedOption + "," + rvalue
                            }
                            else {
                                var tempSelected = rvalue + ",";
                                if (selectedOption.indexOf(tempSelected) != -1)
                                    selectedOption = selectedOption.replace(tempSelected, "");
                                else
                                    selectedOption = selectedOption.replace(rvalue, "");
                            }
                            parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_selectedyears").setValue(selectedOption);


                            //To Set Picklist Select Text
                            var selectedYear = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_selectedyeartext").getValue();
                            if (this.checked) {
                                if (selectedYear == null)
                                    selectedYear = rText;
                                else
                                    selectedYear = selectedYear + "," + rText
                            }
                            else {
                                var tempSelectedtext = rText + ",";
                                if (selectedYear.indexOf(tempSelectedtext) != -1)
                                    selectedYear = selectedYear.replace(tempSelectedtext, "");
                                else
                                    selectedYear = selectedYear.replace(rText, "");
                            }
                            parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_selectedyeartext").setValue(selectedYear);

                        })
                        .appendTo(checkboxList);
                }
            });
        }
    </script> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head><body>
    <div id="checkboxList">
     
    </div>

</body></html>
```

Refer below given link for

[enter link description here](https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.in/2015/02/convert-option-set-to-multi-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

No code needed for that. It's just configuration on CRM to change the display format : checkbox.